# Can filter function be use with groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by

I have this kind of data frame which consist of 100 question

```
|Date|QID|Time_1|Answer_1|Time_2|Answer_2|Time_3|Answer_3|
|1/12|001|20    |  A     |  30  |   A    |  34  |   D    |
|1/12|001|22    |  A     |  10  |   A    |  12  |   D    |
|1/12|002|27    |  B     |  40  |   A    |  45  |   D    |
|1/12|002|25    |  A     |  60  |   C    |  23  |   D    |
```

So, I want the descriptive statistic for a time such as max, min, mean

I use this code:

```
df.groupby('QID')["Time_1","Time_2"].agg(['min','max', 'mean'])
```

And I get this output:

```
       Time_1      Time_2
    min max mean min max mean
QID                     
001 20  22  21   10  30   20
002 25  27  26   40  60   50
```

But because I have more data, I want to use this code and I get an error.

```
df_sample.groupby('QID')[df_sample.filter(like='Time')].agg(['min','max', 'mean'])
```

`TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Does anyone know any other way or any simple way? Thank you

Comment: whats the desired output?

Comment: tried `df_sample.groupby('QID')[*df_sample.filter(like='Time')].agg(['min','max', 'mean'])`?

Comment: try `df_sample.groupby('QID')[df_sample.filter(like='Time').columns].agg(['min','max', 'mean'])`